# clojure: remove a set of strings from a sentence

Tags: string, replace, clojure

I have a sentence "china beijing shanghai USA australia", and a set of words #{"USA" "australia"}

Now i am writting a function which takes input as sentence and set of words, and remove those from sentence :

```
(defn remove-words-from-sentence [sentence words]
  (for [w words] (-> sentence
                     (.replaceAll w "")))
```

Note : I wish to replace exact word occurance.. so if words contains letter "a", then all a's should not be replaced in sentence, only word a should be replaced.

But the above function doesn't work, any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it is by splitting the sentence into individual words, and having the words to be removed in a set, and filter out the words from the sentence.

```
(let [sentence (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" ")
      words (set (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" "))]
  (clojure.string/join " "
                       (filter (complement words)
                               sentence)))



user=> china beijing shanghai USA australia ;;input sentence
user=> china USA ;;input words
user=> "beijing shanghai australia" ;;output
```

EDIT:

[Thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1562315/thumbnail) brought to my attention that `(filter (complement pred) coll)` is equivalent to `(remove pred coll)`. You can verify that by viewing the source code of `remove`

```
(source remove)
(defn remove
  "Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which
  (pred item) returns false. pred must be free of side-effects."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [pred coll]
  (filter (complement pred) coll))
nil
```

So one could just use `remove` instead

```
(let [sentence (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" ")
      words (set (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" "))]
  (clojure.string/join " " (remove words sentence)))
```

It's even more readable that way. You can read it as "remove words from sentence".

Comment: Set will change the order ??

Comment: No. While it's true that set doesn't preserve the order, this has no effect here, because the words that are to be removed are the set, not the sentence. So the order of the words in the sentence is untouched, only the words that are removed are in a set for fast look ups.

Answer (score 0):

`for` iterates over the seq given to it, producing another sequence. So, you're generating a list with elements representing each replacement separately but not combined.

What you want is first replacing the first word, then - on the result of that replacement - remove the second one, and so on. This is a typical case for `reduce`:

```
(defn remove-words-from-sentence
  [sentence words]
  (reduce #(.replace % %2 "") sentence words))
```

(Note that `replace` does the same as `replaceAll` but with literal replacements, not allowing a regular expression.)

**EDIT:** This is only fixing what the OP was trying to do. It will probably produce unwanted results if e.g. one of the words is "eij" (since it will remove that portion of "Beijing"). One way to fix that would be to use `(.replaceAll % (str "\\b\\Q" %2 "\\E\\b\\s*") "")` to do the replacement; and then `trim` the result. A more reliable version might thus look like this:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as string])
(defn remove-words-from-sentence
  [sentence words]
  (let [pattern (->> (for [w words] (str "\\b\\Q" w "\\E\\b"))
                     (string/join "|")
                     (format "(%s)\\s*"))]
    (.trim (.replaceAll sentence pattern ""))))
```

But it all depends on what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
user> (defn remove-words-from-sentence
        [sentence & words]
        (loop [sentence sentence
               ws words]
          (if-not (seq ws)
            sentence
            (recur
             (clojure.string/replace sentence (first ws) "")
             (rest ws)))))
#'user/remove-words-from-sentence
user> (remove-words-from-sentence "Hello, World" "World")
;=> "Hello, "
user> (remove-words-from-sentence "Hello, World" "ll" "o" "H")
;=> "e, Wrld"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far don't deal with the questions specified input types (string and set)

As the input words are specified in the question as a set, and the sentence a string - the easiest solution would probably be using sets - easy to understand too;

```
(defn remove-words-from-sentence [sentence words]
    (str/join " "(set/difference (into #{} (str/split sentence #" ")) words))
)
```

Works as advertised:

```
(remove-words-from-sentence "china beijing shanghai USA australia" #{"USA" "australia"}) 
"beijing china shanghai"
```

Comment: Will set not change the order of string ?

Comment: True.You could do it with an orderedset. (flatland.ordered.set)